# 2003 Dodge ram 1500 4.7 v8

Tags: dodge, fuel-injection, catalytic-converter, cranks-wont-run, ram

My 03 Dodge ram 1500 is cutting out, won't stay running. I've changed all 8 spark plugs and all 8 coils, I had to replace the breather box and assembly as well because my ex had tried to put a cold air intake on it and didn't do it right. The check engine light is not on and I have had it scanned it does not throw a code, any idea what could be going on?

Comment: Sounds like a vacuum leak somewhere at the intake manifold. More than likely a vacuum hose is broken or did not get put back on.

Comment: How long does it stay running? Does it start run until warm then stall? Start and stall?